# CSS Sticky Footer

Tags: css

I know this question has been asked a million times and there are a million articles about it.  I have tried several of the solutions offered, but none have worked for me.  I've only been working with HTML/CSS for a few months off and on, so I'm not very good with it yet and I'm hoping someone will be nice enough to take the time to help me out.

I'm creating a blog layout and everything seems to be working fine except the footer.  I can't get it to stay at the bottom of the page.  Right now it is floating in the middle of the content. I want a footer that is anchored to the bottom of the page and is only visible if the content on the page is very short.  In other words, I want a footer like the one on this website, not one I can achieve using position:fixed.  I really don't know what I'm doing wrong, but like I said, I'm new to this stuff.

Here's the code I'm currently using, though I have changed it around a lot according to various tutorials and nothing has worked for me.

Also, since I'm new at this, if any of you more experienced people see something not related to the footer that I'm doing wrong, I would appreciate it if you could point it out so I can learn how to do this stuff the right way.

Thanks!!

```
    <body>
    <div id="outer">
    <div id="header">
        <div id="wrap">
       <div class="logo"><a href="#"><img src="images/logo.png" /></a>
        </div><!--end logo div--!>

    </div><!--end wrap div--!>
    </div><!--end header div--!>
    <div id="wrap">
    <div id="content">

    <div class="featured_title"><a href="#">Example Title One</a></div>
    <div class="featured_category"><p>Posted in <a href="#"> News</a></p>
    </div><!--end cateogry div--!>
    <div class="featured_excerpt">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam 

    malesuada in orci ornare et porta nisi tristique. Integer sodales feugiat     </p>
    </div><!--end featured excerpt div--!>
    <div class="featured_read">
    <p><a href="#">Read More</a></p>
    </div><!--end featured_read div--!>

    <div id="post_thumbnail">
    <img src="images/sample_pic.jpg" />

    </div>
    <div id="post content">
    <div id="post_info">
    <div class="post_title">
     Example Title Two
    </div><!--end post title div--!>
    <div class="category">
    Posted in <a href="#"> Career Tips</a>
     </div>
     <div class="post_excerpt">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam malesuad
      </p>
    </div><!--end post excerpt div--!>
     <div class="read_post">
    <p><a href="#">Read More</a></p>
     </div><!--end read post div--!>
    </div><!--end post info div--!>
    <div class="divider"><img src ="images/divider.png" /></div>
    </div><!--end post content div--!>
    <div class="more_stories">
    <p><a href="#">Previous Stories</a></p>
    </div><!--end more stories div--!>


    </div>

    </div><!--end content div--!>
    </div><!--end wrap div---!>
    <div id="wrap">
     <div id="sidebar">
     <div class="job_search">
    <a href=#"><img src="images/job_search.png" /></a>
    </div>

    <div class="post_job">
    <a href="#"><img src="images/post_job.png" /></a>
     </div><!--end post_job div--!>

    </div><!--end sidebar div--!>

     </div><!--end wrap div--!>

    </div><!--end outer div--!>
    <div id="footer">

    </div><!--end footer div--!>



    </body>
```

And the CSS

```
    html {height:100%; padding:0; height:100%; }

     body { margin: 0 0 40px; background: #f4f4f4; height:100%; }


    #wrap { margin: 0 auto; width: 940px; }

    /* Header */

    #header { width:100%; height: 50px; background: #000; repeat:x; }

    .logo { margin-left:380px; }


     /* End Header Section */

    /*main content section*/

    #content { width: 558px; padding: 15px; float:left; position:absolute; 
    padding-top150px; min-height:100%; }

    .featured_title { font-family:Georgia, serif; font-size: 1.7em; color: #4e4e4e; }

    .featured_title a { text-decoration:none; color: #4e4e4e; }

    .featured_title a:hover { text-decoration:underline; }



    .featured_category { font-weight:bold; font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif; 
    color:#4e4e4e; font-size: 1em; }

     .featured_category a{ font-weight:bold; color: #d76186; font-size: 1em;

    text-decoration:none; }

    .featured_category a:hover { color:#68acc2; }

    .featured_excerpt { color:#4e4e4e; font-family:helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:   

    .9em;}

     .featured_read a { font-weight:bold; color:#d76186; font-size: 1em;
    text-decoration: none; font-family:helvetica, sans-serif; }

     .featured_read a:hover { color:#68acc2; }

    .featured_read { border-bottom: 2px solid #4e4e4e; padding-bottom: 5px; }

    #post_thumbnail { width:300px; height:200px; padding-top:9px; position:absolute;}

     #post_info { position:relative; height:200px; width:248px; left:320px; top:15px; }

    .post_title { font-family:georgia, serif; font-size:1.2em; color: #4e4e4e; }

     .category { font-weight:bold; color: #4e4e4e; font-size:.8em; 
     font-family:helvetica, sans-serif; padding-top:3px; }

    .category a{ font-weight:bold; color:#d76186; text-decoration:none; }

     .category a:hover { color:#68acc2; }

    .post_excerpt { color:#4e4e4e; font-family:helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:.8em; }

    .read_post a { font-weight:bold; color:#d76186; font-size: .8em; 
    text-decoration:none; font-family:helvetica, sans-serif; }

    .read_post a:hover { color:#68acc2; }

     .divider { padding-top:25px; }

     .more_stories a{ text-decoration:none; font-family:helvetica; color: #d76186;}

    .more_stories a:hover {color: #68acc2;}

    /* sidebar */
    #sidebar { width:317px; left:20px; top:0; position:relative; float:right; 
     min-height:100%; }

   .job_search { padding-bottom:20px; }

    /* Footer */

    #footer { clear:both; bottom:0; background:#000; width:100%;
    height:35px; margin-top: -100px; position:relative; }

     .footer_content { font-family:helvetica, sans-serif; color: #68acc2; }
```

Answer (score 0):

this is not a vallid/right comment

```
 <!--end logo div--!>
```

should be

```
<!-- end logo div -->
```

and try

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="main" class="clearfix">
    </div>
 </div>

<div id="footer">
</div>
```

css

```
html, body, #wrapper{ height: 100%; }
body > #wrapper{height: auto; min-height: 100%;}
#main { padding-bottom: 150px; }  /*  same height as the footer */
#footer { 
        position: relative;
    margin-top: -150px; /* negative value of footer height */
    height: 150px;
    clear:both;} 

.clearfix:after {content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;}
.clearfix {display: inline-block;}
```

Comment: This didn't work for me.  What I did was remove the absolute positioning in the #content div and it seems to work. I haven't tested it in IE yet though

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
#footer{position:absolute; bottom:0;}
```

Comment: That was the first thing I tried.  Unfortunately, the footer was still floating in the middle of the page.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this question has been resolved, but I had the same issue. After a lot of research and hours of frustrating coding I was finally able to come up with a sticky footer that stuck to the bottom of any window, even if there wasn't enough content to push it to the bottom, and the best part is it didn't overlap any content (no matter what size the window was), but instead stopped at the bottom of the content.

Check out my jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/juroto/HL6Ad/

to see how I made it and feel free to use the code ;D

*I tried looking at your code, but you have a bit to much going on for a simple answer. First off you definitely need to fix those HTML notes like NullPonyPointer pointed out. I also caught an extra `</div>` under `</div><!--end more stories div--!>` that needs to be deleted and in your `#content` CSS `padding-top150px;` needs to be `padding-top: 150px;` (you forgot the semicolon). I think there were some other errors I overlooked while trying to solve your problem because in the end, for some reason I couldn't get the sticky footer to work quite right with the code you supplied. I would suggest starting over with a lot less code and then slowly adding your previous code back in after getting the sticky footer to work. I tried to make the fiddle as simple as possible and I left pretty detailed instructions in both the HTML & CSS notes. Sorry I couldn't tell you exactly what to change in your code, but hopefully the fiddle helps! Otherwise, I would just start here:*

```
<!doctype html>

    <head>

        <title>INSERT TITLE</title>

        <style>
            body {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                height: 100%;
            }
            html {
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            * html #wrapper {
                height:100%; 
            }
            #wrapper {
                min-height: 100%;
                position: relative;
            }
            #content {
                padding-bottom: 30px; /* ATTENTION! padding-bottom should be equal to the footer height (this keeps the footer from overlapping the content) */
                font-size: 10em; /* ATTENTION! this font-size can be deleted or changed to whatever your heart desires*/
            }
            #footer {
                position: absolute;
                width: 100%;
                clear: both;
                bottom: 0;
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
                /* ATTENTION! The following elements below 
                can be set to whatever your heart desires */
                height: 30px; /* REMEMBER #footer height = #content padding-bottom */
                background: #333;
            }
        </style>

    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="content">INSERT CONTENT HERE</div>
            <div id="footer"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```